# Laravel 6 user auth page not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-6

Today I installed laravel 6.x version for a new project.

I have PHP 7.3 in my system so laravel 6 was successfully installed.

Then I run this command to set the Auth UI for VueJS.

```
artisan ui vue —auth
```

along with this command:

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

But when I checked my login page, it was just an html skeleton.

I checked over the internet and found a solution and tried to run this command,

```
npm run dev
```

**But still am getting an ugly login page without css and Js files**. I checked for CSS and JS files but found no solution.

Anyone please help and tell me how can I setup the front end scaffolding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you load the JS and CSS files in your template, or aren't they found in the public folder?

Comment: I have both js and css files in pubic folder but they are empty.

Comment: so does the `npm run dev` gives you any errors? And can you show us your `mix-manifest.json` file?

Comment: Did You run this command

npm install

npm run dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The command to implement Auth is as follows:**

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

**If your Login and Register page only shows plain HTML. And CSS is not loading properly then run this two command:**

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

**OR**

**Simply you've to follow this two-step.**

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui:auth
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will solve your problem for sure!**

Check if your npm install shows any deprecation error, 
if shows then go to nodejs official site https://nodejs.org/en/ and download and install latest one in your system.

Then in your terminal run:

```
    npm install  
    npm run dev
```

That's it.

In your laravel public folder, css and js should have shown after that npm run dev command.
Now your login and register page should be nice looking as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Do one thing,

1) Create app.css and put into project_name/public/css/

2) Create app.js and put into project_name/public/js/

I believe it will work.

If not, make sure you have used these commands before.

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Thanks.